# Square's Retrofit Client. Variable number of parameters

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm using Square's Retrofit library. I need to implement request with variable number of parameters. I've found suggestion ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580223/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-base-request-parameter-to-be-included-in-every-request-m?rq=1)) and I try this:

I change

```
@GET("someURL")
void method(
        @Query("firstParameter") int firstValue,
        @Query("secondParameter") String secondValue,
        Callback<Response> cb
);
```

to

```
@POST("someURL")
void method(
        @Body Map<String, Object> parameters,
        Callback<Response> cb
);
```

and use follow:

```
final HashMap<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put("firstParameter", firstValue);
param.put("secondParameter", secondValue);
```

The first way works great, but the second one doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580062/how-can-i-configure-squares-retrofit-client-to-handle-a-request-with-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're switching from a GET to a POST, so instead of passing query parameters, you are passing values in the body.

Retrofit doesn't currently support variable arguments in GET requests. A ticket to add support for this is tracked in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/293