# Android retrofit send body with different converter than response

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit in my android app, and for the response I want to use
SimpleXMLConverter.
However, in the body I want to send simple name-pair values.

The retrofit documentation states:

> The object (body)will also be converted using the RestAdapter's
>   converter.

Is there a way I can send a body in a different converter than the response I am getting (e.g. the response is in XML, the body is just name-value pairs)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a Converter has 2 methods : `fromBody` and `toBody` the first is used for responses, the second for requests. You absolutely can write your own converter that does 2 different things in those methods.

Comment: take a look at the implementation for `SimpleXMLConverter`, you can simply change the behavior of the `toBody` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
After looking into it I saw there is a simpler solution to the specific problem described.
As opposed to sending xml or json, I just want to send name value pairs.

[taken from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063873/how-to-pass-mapstring-string-parameters-or-object-to-post-request-via-retrofi?rq=1)



 \@FormUrlEncoded
\@POST("/oauth/access_token")
void getToken(
    \@FieldMap Map<String, String> params, 
    Callback<FacebookLoginUserResponse> callback
);

This way I get to send name value pairs in post body, and the parser is ignored.