# Posting a Hashmap using retrofit

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

i am trying to post the HashMap using the retrofit. i know there are questions about the same topic in stack overflow but nothing seems like helping me.

here is mt Interface

```
@POST("/" + AppConstants.DIR + "/" + AppConstants.response)
Call<CommonSuccMsgBean> postResponse(@Body HashMap<String,String> hashMap);
```

and here is my method call:

```
public void postResponse(final Context context, HashMap hashMap) {

    try {
        final ProgressDialog pLoading = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pLoading.show();
        pLoading.setTitle("Loading...");
        Call<CommonSuccMsgBean> call = Utilities.getInstance().initializeWebServiceCall(context).postResponse(hashMap);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<CommonSuccMsgBean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<CommonSuccMsgBean> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                System.out.println("succedded");
                CommonSuccMsgBean succMsgBean = response.body();
                /*if (succMsgBean.getSucc().equals("1")){
                    Toast.makeText(MerchantActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/

                pLoading.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                pLoading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i tried the answer give here:
[How to pass Map<String, String> parameters or object to POST request via Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063873/how-to-pass-mapstring-string-parameters-or-object-to-post-request-via-retrofi)

And since number of fields in the hashmap can vary i dont want to use it like...

```
  public interface SafeUserApi {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/userlogin")
void getUserLogin(@Field("client_id")String  id,@Field("client_secret")String  secret,@Field("username")String  uname,@Field("password")String  password, Callback<LoginResult> cb);
```

}

The webservice is working fine when i checked using **POSTMAN** but when i call it from my app it gives some page source as a response.
So is there any way that i can pass whole hashmap as a body? and what i am doing wrong? 
Thanks :)