# Retrofit2 Map<Object, String> call incompatible types error

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit 2 for JSON parsing. I have to make a Map call for my project. Here is my code:

```
    retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call =restInterface.getChannels();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Map<String, Channel>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Map<String, Channel>> response) {
            Map<String, Channel> body = response.body();
            for (Channel channel : body.values()) {
                System.out.println(channel.getSong());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
```

I get incompatible type error and Android Studio suggest to turn here:

```
retrofit2.Call<Map<String, Channel>> call =restInterface.getChannels();
```

to this:

```
retrofit2.Call<List<Channel>> call =restInterface.getChannels();
```

I know it is because Retrofit's original type but for my project I have to do this call. Here you can see how my JSON look like in the API:

```
{  
   "channel0":{  
      "song":"Cry Cry",
      "artist":"Oceana",
      "duration":"180",
      "playedat":"1545158211",
      "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/550513f3aaa5b80648972e715af345e5.png"
   },
   "channel1":{  
      "song":"Phantom Of The Opera",
      "artist":"Iron Maiden",
      "duration":"420",
      "playedat":"1545158002",
      "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/b2cf018fb80147428b698452b2512996.png"
   },
   "channel2":{  
      "song":"Carmen Cubana",
      "artist":"Klazz Brothers",
      "duration":"180",
      "playedat":"1545158161",
      "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/d518730378364a72ab98460bd0fe3d1a.png"
   },
   "channel3":{  
      "song":"Shut Up And Let Me Go",
      "artist":"The Ting Tings",
      "duration":"120",
      "playedat":"1545158234",
      "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/c5805b786a3e4f19b747c7a3dbb41d15.png"
   },
   "channel4":{  
      "song":"The Racing Rats",
      "artist":"Editors",
      "duration":"240",
      "playedat":"1545158095",
      "image_extralarge":"https:\/\/lastfm-img2.akamaized.net\/i\/u\/300x300\/62544562d1904884b6e47804cf1ede1d.png"
   }
}
```

So, how can I do it? I don't know much about this topic so I'm totally open to suggestions or examples for my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your two examples of `.Call` are identical. Is this on purpose? Also, show the exact error message you get as text.

Comment: We also don't see the API you have defined that you are trying to Call. Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/33428445/1531971 relevant?

Comment: @jdv Corrected it and also I add an example of my JSON. Thanks for the warning. Also, I checked your link. I think it is not related the situation I got.

Comment: As one of the answers has mentioned, you still haven't shown your interface for the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with how you have defined your Retrofit service interface. Somewhere you should have an `interface` that looks like this:

```
public interface MyRetrofitService {

    @GET("/some/url")
    Call<List<Channel>> getChannels();
}
```

You will have to change this to return a `Map<String, Channel>` instead of a list:

```
public interface MyRetrofitService {

    @GET("/some/url")
    Call<Map<String, Channel>> getChannels();
}
```